# Restart systemd service when output is no longer generated

Tags: systemd, output, timeout

Is it possible to restart a systemd service when there is no output generated for a predefined amount of time?

I have a script which apparently can hang, but that is not detected by systemd (or Python for that case), and thus it does not enter the failed state.

However, it does stop logging output, so I should be able to restart the service after no output is given for a minute. Is this possible with systemd?

My current systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=SOmething
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/system/something
User=nobody
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 something.py
Restart=on-watchdog
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does your app write output to any log file?  Or just to `stdout` for `systemd` to report on?

Comment: Currently it is only outputting to `stdout`, but that would of course be something that can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think systemd allows you to do that, at least the [`systemd.service(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) manual page doesn't seem to mention anything like that.

However, what you could do is use systemd's builtin watchdog.

You would do that by setting `WatchdogSec=` and then having your service send `WATCHDOG=1` with `sd_notify` regularly. If you set `WatchdogSec=30` then your service must notify systemd at least every 30 seconds.

When your service hangs, it won't notify systemd anymore, and systemd will kill your service as a result.

With `restart=on-watchdog` (which you already have, but it doesn't do anything without `WatchdogSec=`), then systemd will restart your service after it's been killed by the watchdog.

Comment: Although this requires me to adjust the Python-code (it is not my own), it is a good solution for my problem. Thank you for your extensive answer!